# Delete leading zeros of each column of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table `DT` and want to substitute leading zeros of each column with a `NA`.

```
for (n in 1:ncol(DT)) {
  tmp <- as.vector(unlist(DT[,..n]))
  tmp[cumsum(tmp) == 0] <- NA
}
```

But now I don't know how to assign the vector `tmp` back to the n-th column of `DT`.

Also how `tmp` is created is not satisfying.

Comment: Can't an `sapply/vapply` option with `stringr::str_replace_all` or `gsub` do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if by 'leading zeros' you mean 'the first zero of each column'. In that case you could do something like this:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == 0 & !duplicated(x), NA, x))]

#     n  m
# 1: NA  1
# 2:  1 NA
# 3:  0  2
```

If you meant 'any zero in the first row', then:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(cumsum(x) == 0, NA, x))]

#     n m
# 1: NA 1
# 2:  1 0
# 3:  0 2
```

Data:

```
DT <- data.table(n = c(0, 1, 0), m = c(1, 0, 2))

DT

#    n m
# 1: 0 1
# 2: 1 0
# 3: 0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to replace all initial 0-value rows with `NA` for each column.

In this case, it's probably best to use `set`:

```
for (jj in names(DT)) {
  set(DT, 1:(which.min(DT[[jj]] == 0) - 1L), jj, NA)
}
```

NB: You may need to be more careful about `NA` since you'll have to provide the *correct* `NA` according to the column type.

```
types = sapply(DT, typeof)
for (jj in names(DT)) {
  set(DT, 1:(which.min(DT[[jj]] == 0) - 1L), jj,
      switch(types[jj],
             'logical'   = NA,
             'integer'   = NA_integer_,
             'numeric'   = NA_real_,
             'character' = NA_character_,
             'complex'   = NA_complex_,
             stop("No known NA value for type", types[jj]))
       )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace each first zero for each column with NA:

```
DT <- data.table(A = c(0, 1, 0, 2), B = c(1, 0, 2, 0), C = c(1, 1, 2, 0))
DT

# Output
  A B C
1 0 1 1
2 1 0 1
3 0 2 2
4 2 0 0

# DT to DF
df <- as.data.frame(DT)

# Replacing each first zero for each column with NA
for (col in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[min(which(df[, col] == 0)), col] <- NA
}
df

# Output
   A  B  C
1 NA  1  1
2  1 NA  1
3  0  2  2
4  2  0 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version that would also work in base `R` (that is if DT was a `data.frame`:

```
DT[!sapply(DT, duplicated) & DT == 0] <- NA
> DT
    n  m
1: NA  1
2:  1 NA
3:  0  2
```

Data:

```
DT <- data.table(n = c(0, 1, 0), m = c(1, 0, 2))
```